# Rest assured: Size of json response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am new to rest assured. I have tried below code for getting response

```
@Test
    public void getData() throws IOException {
         Response response = 
                    given().
                        header("authToken",userToken).
                    when().
                        get("/students").
                    then().
                        contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                    extract().
                        response(); 
                    String jsonStr = response.getBody().asString();
                    System.out.println("Tag List************************" + jsonStr);

        }
```

This is json response

```
{"max":"20","list":[
{"id":1120,"sId":1120,"sIntId":"150","type":1},
{"id":1121,"sId":1121,"sIntId":"151","type":1}
{"id":1122,"sId":1122,"sIntId":"152","type":1}
{"id":1123,"sId":1123,"sIntId":"153","type":1}
{"id":1124,"sId":1124,"sIntId":"154","type":1}]}
```

How to calculate size of `id's or list`.  Help me.

Comment: Gautam, by chance do you have any document how to configure Rest-assured?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to extract the response to validate this. You can just do like this:

```
given().
       header("authToken",userToken).
when().
       get("/students").
then().
       contentType(ContentType.JSON).
       body("list.size()", is(5));
```

But if you want to extract it from the response you can as well:

```
Response response = 
given().
       header("authToken",userToken).
when().
       get("/students").
then().
       contentType(ContentType.JSON).
extract().
       response(); 
int sizeOfList = response.body().path("list.size()");
```

If you're only interested in the size of the list and nothing else you can do like this:

```
int sizeOfList = 
given().
       header("authToken",userToken).
when().
       get("/students").
then().
       contentType(ContentType.JSON).
extract().
       path("list.size()");
```

Answer (score 0):

if just count the size of `list`, Maybe you can:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(count(jsonStr, "\"id\""));
}

public static int count(String source, String sub) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; (i = source.indexOf(sub, i)) != -1; i += sub.length()) {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;

}
```

Or Regex:

```
public static int countByRegex(String source, String pattern) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(source);

    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
System.out.println(countByRegex(str, "id"));
```